# Playing a imacro loop from VBS script

Tags: imacros

i am trying to execute an iMacro script using a VBS script. I am using `play()` method. but it seems `play()` doesn't support the loop functionality. I searched through the iMacros wiki and Google and unable to find an answer.

Here is the code

```
Set iim1 = CreateObject ("IMacros")
i = iim1.iimInit() 

i = iim1.iimPlay("amazon_search")

i = iim1.iimExit()
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: play will run stated script only once. If you need to loop it insert play inside loop.

Comment: i did a `do loop` but it only read the same first line of data

Comment: well, I don't see any loop in the code you have posted

Answer (score 0):

```
//Scripts by Talon
var nameoffile = "my100.csv"
var numberOfUrls = 101
for(var i=1;i<numberOfUrls;i++){
//sets basic requirements
//do what you want here
var macro = "CODE: "
macro+= "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n"
macro+= "SET !REPLAYSPEED fast"+"\n"
macro+= "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1"+"\n"
macro+= "SET !DATASOURCE "+nameoffile+"\n"
macro+= "SET !LOOP "+i+"\n"
macro+= "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}"+"\n"
macro+= "URL GOTO={{!COL1}}"+"\n"
//Add what you want to do at each site here if using macro format
iimPlay(macro)
Or add your new iimPlay code here , or add more jscript
}
```

The above code uses jscript to call imacros script, in this example I'm first calling a file named my100.csv. my 100 has 100 urls, or website that I go to to pull different information, or to set different information.
the numberOfUrls variable tells my code how many times to run my code.

I then dimension the variable "macro" and build the imacros script, one line at a time, setting the predefined builtin variables how I want them.
Once everything is set I call my first url, and manipulate the data how I want.
NOTE: you do not have to use Urls in you .csv file, you could place your data in the .csv file and go to a site them run your information whatever way you want.